# InputBox в Visual C++ (Visual Studio 2012 C++/CLI)

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте , вот только начал разбираться с графическим интерфейсом . Появилась необходимость получить данные от пользователя через InputBox (подобно как в Delphi) . 
Читал что можно самому сделать на базе диалогового окна ,но пока что не хватает знаний чтобы сделать самому . 
Может быть у кого-то есть готовое решение или сможете объяснить как сделать . 
Спасибо большое заранее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишут, что вроде нет там готового окошка  с такой функциональностью. Но вот [статья](http://kryaker.freeoda.com/index.php/univer/51-inputbox), где описывают, как его сделать самостоятельно. Там правда все на шарпе, но перейти на .нет версию с++ будет не сложно.

Но, пока не поздно, переходите на шарп или на полноценный с++.